# Settings don't display when tabs are clicked on an existing CiviReport

Tags: civireport

Based on the doc found here (at the bottom): https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/reporting/set-up , it should be possible to edit existing reports (like adding email settings). Currently not even copying a report makes it editable, so everytime a new report needs to be created if you want to permanently change a setting (email in my case, to automatically send report results).
So my question: how do I edit an existing report?

Edit: screenshot added[image: report screenshot]
Edit: second screenshot added [image]

Comment: hey franky - i actually think you should leave your answer as is. it is the correct answer - your medication meant you could not see what was in front of your eyes. or just delete the question if you prefer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing the "Administer Reports" permission.

- Go to CiviCRM's **Administer menu » Users and Permissions » Permissions (Access Control).
- Select the first option ("CMS Access Control", where "CMS" is the name of your CMS).
- Assign the "CiviReport: administer Reports" permission to a role you have.
- Save the permission.

It's also worth replicating a problem on the demo site (demo.civicrm.org) if this doesn't resolve your issue.  That way you can edit your question knowing if the problem you're experiencing is specific to your site, or to CiviCRM in general.

Comment: I'm using wordpress, and I'm a wordpress administrator, so I'm not even able to assign these permissions to my role (according to the doc, WP admins have all rights in civicrm) ...

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add a screenshot (of the report screen with the problem, not the permissions screen)?  I may be misunderstanding what you're seeing.

Comment: Sure, screenshot added ... just difficult to show something that isn't there (the "edit" report thingie ...)

Comment: Ah - that IS different than I expected.  I thought the "E-mailverzending" tab would be missing - not that the contents wouldn't appear if you clicked on the tab.  This looks like a Javascript error.  Please a) try disabling all extensions on a test copy of your site to see if there's a conflict, and b) look at the Troubleshooting Javascript in CiviCRM page here: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850

Comment: Thanks for your help already.
What I tried:
- disable literally all other plugins: no effect  
- javascript console: no errors  
- debugging in civicrm: nothing shown  
It seems the "edit report" (or something alike) is not even in the dropdown (see second attached screenshot)

Comment: Ah - I misunderstood completely from your first screenshot!  I thought that you couldn't see the entire "E-mailinstellingen" section that is present in your second screenshot but not your first.  You should be able to select "Save" ("Opslaan") after you change the email values and your changes should persist.  Could you please try to replicate your problem on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ and let us know if you have the same problem there?

Comment: I must have been blind all along ... "Opslaan" means "Save" and it seems it was there all along (must have been on drugs ... the only reasonable thing I can say in my defense it that it is selected by default in the actions dropdown, so maybe that's why I missed it ...). Thanks for being so patient with me ...

Comment: I'm glad we worked it out!

Comment: wow. is being on drugs now considered a 'reasonable defence'?